how to know if a token is legacy SPL or Token2022 and transfer Token2022?
Q1: how to how if a token is abid to Token2022 protocol or otherwise SPL token?
for example, does circle USDC on devnet : https://explorer.solana.com/address/4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU?cluster=devnet   a Token2022 token ?
Q2:  does my code bellow work for both SPL ot Token2022 token?
use anchor_spl::token_interface::{transfer_checked, TransferChecked};

...

token_account = minter.key();
let decimals = minter.decimals;
transfer_checked(ctx, amount, decimals).expect("lock token to vault should success");


#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransToken<'info> {
            ...
    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = minter,
        associated_token::authority = user
    )]
    pub user_ata: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,  // user token account

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        associated_token::mint = minter,
        associated_token::authority = sol_vault
    )]
    pub token_vault: Account<'info, TokenAccount>,    // token account on PDA
  
    #[account(
      mut,
    )]
    pub minter: Account<'info, Mint>, 
        ...
}  

The above transfer_checked work under SPL token ( where I create the token myself). But I don't know if it work for Token2022, because I did not got any Token2022 token.
Thanks.

Q1: you need to look at the owner of the account:
$ solana -ud account 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU

Public Key: 4zMMC9srt5Ri5X14GAgXhaHii3GnPAEERYPJgZJDncDU
Balance: 67.147504055 SOL
Owner: TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA

The owner is TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA, which is the legacy SPL Token program. The SPL Token-2022 program's key is TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb.
Q2: you'll need to use the "interface" variants for accounts and programs, ie:
use anchor_spl::{
    token_interface::{
        Mint, TokenAccount, TokenInterface
    },
};
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct TransToken<'info> {
            ...
    #[account(
        mut,
        associated_token::mint = minter,
        associated_token::authority = user
    )]
    pub user_ata: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,  // user token account

    #[account(
        init_if_needed,
        payer = user,
        associated_token::mint = minter,
        associated_token::authority = sol_vault
    )]
    pub token_vault: InterfaceAccount<'info, TokenAccount>,    // token account on PDA
  
    #[account(
      mut,
    )]
    pub minter: InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>, 
        ...
}

Lifted from https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor/blob/master/tests/spl/token-extensions/programs/token-extensions/src/instructions.rs

Wow, very clear answer. I will try it.
